# Attempted Operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator

Tags: powershell, list-view-threshold, sharepoint-server

I am copying list items from one list to other list using powershell script.I am getting below error -

> Exception calling Execute query with zero arguments. The attempted operation is prohibited because  it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

Operations that exceed the list view threshold are allowed in foll.time window defined by admin.daily from 7.30 pm to 8.30 am.

I can able to copy list items till 17000.From then I'm getting the above error.How can i overcome threshold limit issue without changing threshold limit in Central Admin  or indexing.Please Suggest .

Answer (score 2):

You need to batch your request. (strange that it fails at 17K not 5K but maybe you have different levels set up on list or in CA) So to copy items create multiple request in first copy the items with ID 1-17000, in next one copy from 17001-34000 (or do it in 5K chunks)